# Why ThreadPoolExecutor behaves differently when running Java program in Eclipse and from command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, threadpoolexecutor

Can anybody explain why this code throws OOME when I run it from Eclipse (Juno) but works fine when I run it from command line? I use -Xmx256M in both cases.

```
static class Task implements Runnable {
    byte[] buf = new byte[150000000];
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ex.submit(new Task()).get();
    ex.submit(new Task()).get();
}
```

Here is the Eclipse output

```
259522560
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at Test2$Task.<init>(Test2.java:7)
    at Test2.main(Test2.java:17)
```

I ran it on my notebook, cannot be sure how it behaves on other PCs.

Comment: Do you know where exactly the exception is happening? before second submit or after?  did you consider using ex.shutDown() after second submit ?

Comment: exception is trown on second submit, it is line line 17 in original code, so it doesn't make sense to try to add anything after second submit

Comment: If you put a sleep in your task's run do you get an OOME in Eclipse as well? My guess is that when run from the command line the first task has been executed and therefore can be garbage collected by the time the second is submitted. Unless I'm doing my maths wrongly you _should_ be getting an OOME if two objects of your task exist at once.

Comment: @Martin, get() method in the first task, will wait until the task finished. so when we submitting the second task, the first one definitely is finished.

Comment: The task object may still be referenced though, I guess (even if it has finished running) although it's hard to see where.

Comment: So is the question "why isn't the first task being garbage collected before the OOME is thrown when running in Eclipse"?

Comment: It might be a bug in eclipse then. I can run the exact same code in IntelliJ IDEA (community edition 11.1) without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

-- original response --
Eclipse is running with 256M, but did you edit the run config of the app to give the launched application 256aM as well? If not, it will run with default heap.

-- update after question updated --

I tested the code below, and it runs fine in eclipse and outside.

Does the OOME happen at the first run (eg, what does the following output?), and does changing the position of allocation affect things?:

```
public class Test {
    public static class Task implements Runnable {
        byte[] buf;
        int id;
        public Task(int i) {
            id = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            buf = new byte[150000000];
            System.out.println("hi " + id);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        ex.submit(new Task(1)).get();
        ex.submit(new Task(2)).get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant did you go to run > run configurations, select launch shortcut, arguments tag, and in the VM args box type in -Xmx256M?

Comment: I think the question is- are you setting this for your java app or the Eclipse IDE itself? Where are you setting this? How about adding a debug statement to log how much heap is available to confirm?

Comment: Martin is correct. I am suggesting that the solution is to correctly configure the run shortcut in Eclipse to give enough stack. From the author comment, it sounds like that it wasn't the case.

Comment: Tested your code, it worked. Got hi 1, hi 2. Original code still fails. It seems that you know why.

Comment: To my surprise, when I moved buf = new byte[150000000]; inside run() in my code it worked too.