# How can one `finalize` invocation break GC / JVM?

Tags: java

While investigating [Why ThreadPoolExecutor behaves differently when running Java program in Eclipse and from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548809/why-threadpoolexecutor-behaves-differently-when-running-java-program-in-eclipse) I wrote a test that throws a very strange OutOfMemoryError (max mem = 256 Mb)

```
class A {
    byte[] buf = new byte[150_000_000];

    protected void finalize() {
        int i = 1;
    }
}

A a1 = new A();
a1 = null;
A a2 = new A();
```

comment out `int i = 1` and the test works. As far as I understand when `finalize` is empty HotSpot simply ignores it. But how can just one practically empty `finalize` invocation break GC / JVM?

Comment: Interesting question, +1 and a star

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But how can just one empty finalize invocation break GC / JVM?

When there's a finalizer, objects survive one more round of garbage collection than they would otherwise (as the object itself has to be kept alive until it's finalized). Therefore if you have a large object with a finalizer, that will naturally lead to an `OutOfMemoryError` occurring in situations when it wouldn't without a finalizer.

In this code:

```
A a1 = new A();
a1 = null;
A a2 = new A();
```

... the GC will trigger on the last line in order to try to find enough memory to allocate the second `A`. Unfortunately, it can't garbage collect the first `A` (and the array it refers to) because the finalizer hasn't run yet. It *doesn't* wait until the finalizer completes, then try to garbage collect again - it just throws `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: I don't really understand: the object is created in any case -- or isn't it? Do you mean to tell that a1 and a2 are lazily created?

Comment: @fge: The point is that when there's no finalizer, the garbage collector can *immediately* collect the first instance of `A` and the array when it needs to find more memory for the second instance of `A` (and the second array). When there's a finalizer, it can't.

Comment: OK, now that makes a lot of sense! Thanks for the explanation.